# Regex replace for jquery selects

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to target some dynamic form variables using jquery. Only problem is that they contain square brackets (they're array format) and I can't seem to get the regex to work that would correctly find and then replace the string with the correct formatting for jquery.

Demo code :

```
<div id="test[array][1]">wibble</div>
<div id="test[array][2]">wibble</div>
<div id="test[array][3]">WIBBLE</div>
<div id="test[array][4]">WIBBLE</div>
<button onclick="clicky();">test</button>

<script>

function clicky() {
//1 fail
$("#test[array][1]").html("moo");

//2 works
element = "#test\\[array\\]\\[2\\]";
console.log(element);
$(element).html("moo");

//3 fail
element = "#test[array][3]";

element.replace(/\[/g, "\\[");
element.replace(/\[/g, "\\]");
$(element).html("moo");  
console.log(element);

//4 fail     
element = "#test[array][4]";     

element.replace(/\[.*?\]/g,'\\$1');
console.log(element);

 $(element).html("moo");


};    

</script>
```

Array[2] is working but I need to be able to convert a randomly generated string into a version thats acceptable for jQuery. It also confuses me as console.log shows the element with only 1 backslash.

Im passing in a string eg '#test[array][1]' and need to get that into a format which jQuery will accept as an identifier.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be interesting to see what effect it has on the performance, but you could use the selector `[id='test[array][1]']` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the old document.getElementById function and then convert it to a jQuery element if needed.

Sample:

```
$('#clicky').click(function() {    
var element = document.getElementById("test[array][1]");
$(element).html('moo');    
});   ​

<div id="test[array][1]">wibble</div>
<div id="test[array][2]">wibble</div>
<div id="test[array][3]">WIBBLE</div>
<div id="test[array][4]">WIBBLE</div>
<button id="clicky">test</button>
```

​Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/tatzz/2/

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. +1 for avoiding regular expressions too!

Comment: yep, ignore the framework and revert back to 'good old' javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to do your string replacement...

```
element = "#test[array][3]";
element = element.replace(/\[/g, "\\\\[");
element = element.replace(/\]/g, "\\\\]");
$(element).html("moo");  
console.log(element);
```

You need to assign the result of the replace back to the variable.